# How to set spinner values in android those are coming from list?

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-spinner

I have a spinner like below

```
final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.primary_game_spinner);

primary_games = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.primary_game_spinner);
ArrayAdapter<String> games_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(SignupActivity.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, allNames);
primary_games.setAdapter(games_adapter);
```

and the xml is ...

```
<Spinner
            android:id="@+id/primary_game_spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dp" />
```

now i would like to set the values upon data. Meaning that if i select one item in spinner it has to give id of that spinner item.

That values i have in ListArray()...

How can i achieve this?

Thanks & Regards

Comment: What exactly is the question? How to detect an item click on a spinner item, or modify the objects in the `allNames` list?

Comment: allNames is a List variable and it is having all games.. my question is apparent to the all names i need to set values for each and every item. Like Select box in HTML.

Comment: Then wrap the Strings with some Java class that holds both a string and an ID, then load those into an ArrayAdapter

Comment: Could you please provide an example how to do this i didn't do this really before.

Comment: Make a class... `public class SpinnerItem { int id, String value;}`... Build a list of those... Store them in the Adapter. It's just standard Java stuff, make sense?